# Python: calculate with dataframe and dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, calculation

I have a dataframe/excel sheet with transaction types of business processes and how often a transaction type was performed:

| branch | Transaction Type | occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | red | 12 |
| aa | green | 100 |
| bb | blue | 20 |
| cc | red | 12 |
| cc | green | 100 |
| cc | blue | 20 |

I have a second df/excel sheet with processing time in seconds per transaction type

| Transaction Type | time in S |
| --- | --- |
| red | 120 |
| green | 320 |
| blue | 60 |

What i need is a new column in the processes-df, where the # of occurrences is multiplied by the processing time, in order to get the effort in seconds for a specific transaction type:

| branch | Transaction Type | occurrences | Effort in S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa | red | 12 | 1440 |
| aa | green | 100 | 32000 |
| bb | blue | 20 | 1200 |
| cc | red | 12 | 1440 |
| cc | green | 100 | 32000 |
| cc | blue | 20 | 1200 |

[edit]
I was not precise enough. it is not only a simple merge of 2 dataframes, but rather the calculation of the effort per branch....
[/edit]

As i am a beginner with only theoretical knowledge i assume that i have to import my 2 excels with openpyxl and create dataframes with pandas.
Then i need to iterate over the dataframes and maybe with a function (lambda?) i can do this simple calculation.
Maybe it is better to create a dictionary out of the 2nd excel, since it has only 2 columns?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: pandas has a `merge` function similar to SQL `join` to build one frame from the first two. Then the multiplication of the two columns to create a new one is easy and fast.

Comment: hello. tnx for your answer. indeed i was not precise enough, please refer to the edit above. a merge was too simple, i think :)

Comment: Why is the effort for "cc"-"green" only 100?

Comment: i corrected that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"branch":["aa","aa","bb","cc","cc","cc"], "Transaction Type": ["red","green","blue", "red","green","blue"], "occurrences":[12,100,20,12,100,20]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Transaction Type": ["red","green","blue"], "time in S":[120,320,60]})
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner')

df3["Effort in S"] = df3["occurrences"]*df3["time in S"]
df3 = df3.drop("time in S", axis=1).sort_values('branch')
print(df3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas library in python, much easier to do this thing.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(<PATH_TO_FILE>)
df2 = pd.read_csv(<PATH_TO_SECOND_FILE>)
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
final_df = df1 #get first three columns same as df1
final_df.merge(df2, on='Transaction Type', how='left')
final_df['Effort in S'] = final_df['time in S']*final_df['occurrences']
#Incase u need to remove the time in S column
#df.drop('column_name', axis=1, inplace=True)
final_df.to_csv(<PATH_TO_Directory/file_name>, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Edited after seeing you edited the question.